# Postgres: auto-populating an `INSERT` field based on session variable

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I have a web app backed by Postgres.

- Each web app request should only read/write data for the current logged-in user.
- Every table with user data has a `user_id` column.

I occasionally have bugs where I forget to add `user_id = ?` to the `WHERE` clause of an SQL request.  To protect against this problem in a general way, I'm looking into Postgres row-level security ([article](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/application-users-vs-row-level-security/)):

- Set a policy on every user data table: `CREATE POLICY table_policy ON table USING (user_id::TEXT = current_setting('app.user_id'))`
- In the web app, when a request begins, set the current logged-in user ID on the request's connection: `SET app.user_id = ?`.

This allows me to completely ignore `user_id` when writing `SELECT` and `UPDATE` requests.

My remaining problem is `INSERT`s.  Is there a way to avoid having to provide `user_id` on `INSERT`s?

Answer (score 1):

Just having a look at the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createpolicy.html) :

> *Existing table rows are checked against the expression specified in USING, while new rows that would be created via INSERT or UPDATE are
> checked against the expression specified in WITH CHECK*

it seems that you just have to add a `WITH CHECK` clause to your policy in addition of the `USING` clause, and which will apply to the INSERT and UPDATE statements.

Comment: Yes, `INSERT` statements will be checked -- if my `INSERT` specifies the wrong `user_id`, it will be appropriately rejected.  But what I'm looking for is a way to not even have to provide `user_id` in my `INSERT`s.